# How to use Python's S3FS to delete a file that contains dashes and brackets in the filename?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-s3fs

I have a file named `data_[2022-10-03:2022-10-23].csv.gzip` in S3, inside a bucket and folder named `s3://<bucket_name>/data/cache/`

I am attempting to delete this file using S3FS. When I attempt to do so with:

```
filename = 'data_[2022-10-03:2022-10-23].csv.gzip'
data_filepath = 's3://<bucket_name>/data/cache'
fs.rm(f"{data_filepath}/{filename}")
```

But the rm call throws exception:

```
error('bad character range 2-1 at position 54')
```

It seems it is thinking this is a regex.

I attempted escaping it with:

```
filename = filename.replace('[', '\\[').replace(']', '\\]').replace('-', '\\-')
```

but I get the same error:

```
('bad character range \\\\-1 at position 57',)
```

I also tried `re.escape()`:

```
fs.rm(f"{data_filepath}/{re.escape(filename)}")
```

But I get:

```
error('bad character range \\\\-1 at position 57')
```

The same thing.

I tried the delete method:

```
fs.delete(f"{data_filepath}/{filename}")
```

Same error.

I tried accessing the underlying boto3 and deleting directly:

```
bucket_name = '<bucket_name>'
path = 'data/cache'
filename = 'data_[2022-10-03:2022-10-23].csv.gzip'
fs.s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=f'{path}/{filename}')
```

This method executes with no errors, but nothing is deleted.

How can I delete this file?

Comment: Please note that Amazon S3 is an object storage service. It isn't designed to be 'mounted'. It is always preferable to use AWS API calls rather than using tools like s3fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this with `boto3` as below to see it deleting the file as it is:

```
import boto3

def s3_delete():
    fs = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id="########", aws_secret_access_key="########")
    bucket_name = '<bucket-name>'
    path = 'data/cache'
    filename = 'data_[2022-10-03:2022-10-23].csv.gzip'

    fs.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=f'{path}/{filename}')


s3_delete()
```

Comment: I don't know why in my case it is not deleting, nor throwing any kind of error... thanks for testing it though, I suspect this is something outside the code then - maybe in permissions, or something else. I'll mark as answered so as to not confuse anyone who has seen this question.